# Map lists of nested objects with Dapper (3 level nested object)

Tags: c#, .net, orm, asp.net-web-api2, dapper

I'm using Dapper and I have classes like this:

```
public class Region
{
    public Region()
    {
        Countries = new List<Country>(0);
    }
    public int RegionID { get; set; }

    public int RiskRank { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int SiteID { get; set; }

    public string DestinationType { get; set; }

    public string HealixCode { get; set; }

    public string AreaCode { get; set; }

    public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public Country()
    {

    }

    public int CountryID { get; set; }

    public bool IsSecondary { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ISO2Code { get; set; }

    public string ISO3Code { get; set; }

    public ISOCountry ISOCountry { get; set; }

    public IList<CountryAlias> CountryAliases { get; set; }
}

public class CountryAlias
{
    public CountryAlias()
    {

    }
    public int CountryAliasID { get; set; }
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public string Alias { get; set; }
}
```

I can get all information about Regions with all countries with but I would like to know if is possible with one query get also the list of CountryAlias for each country for each region. Actually what I do is this:

```
private const string GetAllForSiteWithoutCountriesSQL = @"SELECT * FROM Regions WHERE ChannelID = @channelID";  

private const string GetAllForSiteWithCountriesSQL = @"SELECT c.*, rc.RegionID
                                                           FROM Regions r
                                                             JOIN RegionCountries rc ON rc.RegionID = r.RegionID
                                                             JOIN Countries c ON (rc.CountryID = c.CountryID AND c.IsSecondary = 0)                                                                 
                                                           WHERE r.ChannelID = @channelID";

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Region>> GetAllAsync(int channelID, bool includeCountries = true)
    {
        var regions = await Database.QueryAsync<Region>(GetAllForSiteWithoutCountriesSQL, new { channelID });

        var regionMap = regions.ToDictionary(r => r.RegionID);

        if (includeCountries)
        {
            await Database.QueryAsync<Country, int, Country>(
                GetAllForSiteWithCountriesSQL,
                (country, regionID) =>
                {
                    regionMap[regionID].Countries.Add(country);
                    return country;
                }, new { channelID }, splitOn: "RegionID");
        }

        return regions;
    }
```

I also found a good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17748734/2204958) but I don't understand how to use it in my case, because I have also the Group class. How should I do this with Dapper, is it possible or the only way is to do different steps? Thanks

Comment: There are a few options, check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508322/how-do-i-map-lists-of-nested-objects-with-dapper/17748734#17748734)

Comment: @franc he already mentions he's looked into that thread in his question.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31047547/4300608), I tried it myself and it seems to work well.

Answer (score 2):

i know this question is old, but i've had the same problem a while ago, for those who still have doubts, you can try the following.

The SQL for both queries:

```
SELECT r.*, c.*, a.*
    FROM Regions as r
        LEFT JOIN Countries as c 
            ON a.RegionID = c.RegionID
                LEFT JOIN CountryAliases as a
                    ON a.RegionID = a.RegionID
    WHERE r.ChannelID  = @ChannelID
```

Still your `Region` object don't have a ChannelID property, so instead you could've done:

**C#**

```
New {RegionID = channelID}
```

**VB.NET**

```
New With {.RegionID = channelID}
```

Also i don't know what this channel is about, but seems to act as a key for your search.

**C#**

```
Dictionary<int, Region> RegionDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Region>();
Await Database.QueryAsync<Region, Country, CountryAlias, Region>(sql,
    (region, country, countryalias) => {
    Region _region = new Region();

    if(!RegionDictionary.TryGetValue(region.RegionID, out _region)){
        RegionDictionary.Add(region.RegionID, _region = region);
    }

    if(_region.Countries == null){
        _region.Countries = new List<Country>();
    }
    if(countryalias != null){
        // begin <this line might be discarded>
        if(country.CountryAliases == null){
            country.CountryAliases = new List<CountryAlias>();
        }
        // end
        country.CountryAliases.Add(countryalias);
    }
    _region.Countries.Add(country);
    return _region;
}, new {channelID}, splitOn: "CountryID, CountryAliasID, RegionID");

return RegionDictionary.Values.ToList();
```

**VB.NET**

```
Dim RegionDictionary As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Region)
Await Database.QueryAsync(Of Region, Country, CountryAlias, Region)(sql,
Function(region, country, countryalias)
    Dim _region As New Region();
    if(!RegionDictionary.TryGetValue(region.RegionID, _region)) Then
        _region = region
        RegionDictionary.Add(region.RegionID, region)
        If IsNothing(_region.Countries) Then
            _region.Countries = new List(Of Country)
        End If
        If Not IsNothing(countryalias) Then
            ' begin <this line might be discarded>
            If IsNothing(country.CountryAliases) Then
                country.CountryAliases = new List(Of CountryAlias)
            End If
            ' end
            country.CountryAliases.Add(countryalias)
        End If
        _region.Countries.Add(country)
    End If
End Function, New With {channelID}, splitOn: "CountryID, CountryAliasID, RegionID")

Return RegionDictionary.Values.ToList()
```

If you're wondering about how can you [work more than 7 types](https://riptutorial.com/dapper/example/1198/mapping-more-than-7-types) with this same logic, you can do:

**C#**

```
Dictionary<int, Region> RegionDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Region>();
Await Database.QueryAsync<Region>(sql,
    new[]
    {
        typeof(Region),
        typeof(Country),
        typeof(CountryAlias)
    },
    obj => {
        Region region = obj[0] as Region;
        Country country = obj[1] as Country;
        CountryAlias countryalias = obj[2] as CountryAlias;
        Region _region = new Region();

        if(!RegionDictionary.TryGetValue(region.RegionID, out _region)){
            RegionDictionary.Add(region.RegionID, _region = region);
        }

        if(_region.Countries == null){
            _region.Countries = new List<Country>();
        }
        if(countryalias != null){
            // begin <this line might be discarded>
            if(country.CountryAliases == null){
                country.CountryAliases = new List<CountryAlias>();
            }
            // end
            country.CountryAliases.Add(countryalias);
        }
        _region.Countries.Add(country);
        return _region;
}, new {channelID}, splitOn: "CountryID, CountryAliasID, RegionID");

return RegionDictionary.Values.ToList();
```

It's all about creating a dictionary then putting some values into it, depending on whether there's already a value with the respective ID or not.

Comment: With the code you provided I cannot have more than one country_alias in my Country.
I have fixed with:

```
var a = _region.Countries.Find(x => x.Id == country.Id);
a?.CountryAliases.Add(countryalias);
```

Comment: good to know that @rinomau.